# Is it not opinion based?

Tags: discussion, questions

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17550/would-a-director-revive-a-dead-character-for-a-sequel) looks opinion based to me. Even placed a close vote to it but community looks acceptable to it. Just want to see if it just got ignored or this kind of question are acceptable?

Comment: I guess it it had never happened it would be somewhat opinion based, but as it happened (several times indeed) its not opinion.  As @NapoleonWilson states - its not a great question, but that doesn't necessarily make it closable.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not so much opinion-based as it is overly broad or speculative and has inspired some invaluable example-answers (along with more valuable and elaborate answers, though). Still I didn't close-vote since I wasn't entirely sure and the community seemed to be content with it.

But I also cannot see in which way this would be opinion-based. It asks a pretty objective question, even if the trivial answer would just be *"Well, of course this is possible, why shouldn't it? Oh, and here's a nice example"*.

Comment: Might be in hurry to close that question, i am just searching for a valid reason. Opinion based came first to me but as a whole i don't think that question is good enough.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Of course we still have to pick the correct reason and for me *"opinion-based"* just isn't one. The question is not good, I agree, but it isn't opinion-based in my opinion. Maybe one could even rephrase it to make it better.

Comment: I would be happy with the question if it was rephrased a little bit to invite less example answers, but I am not sure how to do this without changing the original intent.